# How to import&use javascript functions in jsx?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I want to use connect() javascript function in App.jsx.
I'm using meteor framework.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
/* [I THINK THAT SOME IMPORT CODES SHOULD BE HERE..] */

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          onClick={ /* [I WANT TO USE connect() FUNCTION HERE] */ }
        > Connect </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

connect.js

```
function connect() {
  console.log('connected');
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can export and import this function.

connect.js

```
export function connect() {
  console.log('connected');
}
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from '/path/to/connect.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          onClick={connect}
        > Connect </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```